# Prove that a relation is a total order.

Tags: inequality, ordered-fields

Consider the set $A=\{(x, y) \in \Bbb R\times\Bbb R \,|\, y \le 0\}.$

Prove that the following relation is of total order on $A.$ $$(x,y)\preceq(u,v)\iff (x<u) \vee [(x=u) \wedge (x^2+y^2 \ge u^2+v^2)]$$

Comment: Consider adding context, see e.g. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Do you understand all of the terminology and notation in the question?

Comment: I don't understand how to show symmetry, antisymmetry and transitivity of the whole expression